# Find Centroid of Quadrilateral

Tags: java, centroid, quadrilaterals

Help me please with how to find Centroid of Quadrilateral? I have this constructor:

```
 public Quadrilateral(Point a, Point b, Point c, Point d) {
        if (a == null || b == null || c == null || d == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        if (collinear(a, b, c)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        double[][] points = { { a.getX(), a.getY() }, { b.getX(), b.getY() },
                { c.getX(), c.getY() }, { d.getX(), d.getY() } };

        if (!isConvex(points)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;
    }
```

Then I find four centroids of triangles inside quadrilateral:

```
public Point centroid() {
      Point center1 = centroidTriangle(a,b,c);
      Point center2 = centroidTriangle(a,c,d);
      Point center3 = centroidTriangle(a,d,b);
      Point center4 = centroidTriangle(b,d,c);
        return null;
    }

    private Point centroidTriangle(Point a, Point b, Point c) {
        double xx = (a.getX() + b.getX() + c.getX()) / 3;
        double xy = (a.getY() + b.getY() + c.getY()) / 3;
        return new Point(xx, xy);
    }
```

Then I need to find two diagonals between "leftUp" - "rightDown" and "leftDown"-"rightUp" centroids.
But how can I find position of centroid to make correct pairs of them? And how to find then centroid of all quadrilateral?

Answer (score 2):

Good day.
After finding centers of triangles you need to find intersection of lines which made with (center1,center2) and (center3,center4). So point of intersection is **Centroid of Quadrilateral**

```
  public Point centroid() {
        Point center1 = centroidTriangle(a,b,c);
        Point center2 = centroidTriangle(a,c,d);
        Point center3 = centroidTriangle(a,d,b);
        Point center4 = centroidTriangle(b,d,c);

        return new Segment(center1,center2)
                .intersection(new Segment(center3,center4));

    }
```

Segment:

```
import java.util.Objects;

import static java.lang.Math.sqrt;
import static java.lang.StrictMath.pow;

class Segment {

    Point start;
    Point end;

    public Segment(Point start, Point end) {
        if(Objects.isNull(start) || Objects.isNull(end) || start.equals(end))
            throw new RuntimeException();
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    double length() {
        return sqrt(pow(end.getX() - start.getX(), 2) + pow(end.getY() - start.getY(), 2));
    }

    Point middle() {
        return new Point((start.getX() + end.getX()) / 2, (start.getY() + end.getY()) / 2);
    }

    Point intersection(Segment another) {
        double k1 = (end.getY() - start.getY()) / (end.getX() - start.getX());
        double k2 = (another.end.getY() - another.start.getY()) / (another.end.getX() - another.start.getX());
        if (k1 == k2) return null;

        double b1 = (start.getY() * end.getX() - end.getY() * start.getX()) / (end.getX() - start.getX());
        double b2 = (another.start.getY() * another.end.getX() - another.end.getY() * another.start.getX()) /
                (another.end.getX() - another.start.getX());

        double x = (b2 - b1) / (k1 - k2);
        double y = (k1 * b2 - k2 * b1) / (k1 - k2);

        if ((x > start.getX() && x > end.getX()) || (x > another.start.getX() && x > another.end.getX()) ||
                (x < start.getX() && x < end.getX()) || (x < another.start.getX() && x < another.end.getX()) ||
                (y > start.getY() && y > end.getY()) || (y > another.start.getY() && y > another.end.getY()) ||
                (y < start.getY() && y < end.getY()) || (y < another.start.getY() && y < another.end.getY()))
            return null;


        return new Point(x, y);

    }

}
```